# overfitting with gaussian process regression

Tags: python, gaussian-process, overfitting

I am trying to fit a Gaussian Process model to some data I have. My dataset consists of two sets of 2D points where one set is a transformed function of the other set. The transformation function is non-linear and I am trying to estimate it through a GO model where I would like to fit a smooth transformation and I am using a RBF/Squared exponential kernel for this.

I am using python and the scikit-learn library and my fitting code is as follows:

```
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF

# Use the squared exponential kernel
kernel = RBF(6.0, (1e-5, 1e5))
gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, n_restarts_optimizer=9)
# Fit to data using Maximum Likelihood Estimation of the parameters
gp.fit(X, Y)
```

Here `X` and `Y` are the observations and I am trying to fund the unknown function `T(x)` that should yield `Y`. I have around `300` observations and the shape of `X` and `Y` is `(300, 2)`.

Now, I am trying to evaluate the fit. So, I am plotting the observed values and predicted values in a range. So, I am predicting and plotting the values for the first dimension as follows:

```
coordinates = [[x, 250] for x in range(150, 300)]
coordinates = np.asarray(coordinates)
print(coordinates.shape)

y_pred, sigma = gp.predict(coordinates, return_std=True)

fig = plt.figure()
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], Y[:, 0], c="r", s=0.5, label='observations')
plt.plot(coordinates[:, 0], y_pred[:, 0], 'b-', label='Predictions')
plt.show()
```

[image: X coordinate]

Looking at the y-coordinate, we have:

```
coordinates = [[200, x] for x in range(150, 300)]
coordinates = np.asarray(coordinates)
print(coordinates.shape)

y_pred, sigma = gp.predict(coordinates, return_std=True)

fig = plt.figure()
plt.scatter(X[:, 1], Y[:, 1], c="r", s=0.5, label='observations')
plt.plot(coordinates[:, 1], y_pred[:, 1], 'b-', label='Predictions')
plt.show()
```

And the plot looks as:

[image]

To me, this function looks like it is varying quite wildly. For example, that dip in the X-coordinate. Is there some way I can restrict it to be more constrained in areas where the data points are sparsely sampled.

Comment: The sklearn default for alpha, the noise hyperparameter, is quite small, which should force the predictions to go through all of the training points. I can't quite tell from your plots, but if all the red points are training points, then it's not doing that for some reason?

That reason could be that you've forced the length scale in the RBF to be 1e-5, which is also quite small. Why do you want that to be the length scale?

Comment: Since your values of 'Y' are not zero-mean you should use 'normalize_y=True' in the call to GaussianProcessRegressor. Since you have experimental data, you should also add a WhiteKernel to the RBF kernel

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to use machine learning methods (particularly kernel methods and GPs) with their default hyper-parameter settings ( https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.06777 ).  The standard approach is to tune them by maximising the marginal likelihood (the Bayesian evidence for the model).  However it is possible to over-fit the marginal likelihood as well, although regression models are more tolerant of this than for classification (https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-62416-7_14 pre-print: https://ueaeprints.uea.ac.uk/id/eprint/67158/1/Chapter.pdf).

Comment: As Kevin suggests, if the function is too wiggly, increasing the lengthscale is a good idea.  Essentially GP inference is all about inferring the hyper-parameters, there is no "model" per se.